# Suppress HTML Validation Error in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, html, validation

I have a custom attribute that I use in various elements in my ASP.NET HTML markup. Obviously it violates the DTD, and I get a validation error from Visual Studio. I hate ignoring errors in the error output window. Is there a way to suppress this error message? For example:

```
<label id="MyId" cid="MyCID" runat="server" />
```

cid is a custom attribute I use for various purposes, and it produces a validation error:

```
Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'cid' is not a valid attribute of element label
```

Comment: It is a means of transmitting data from the server to the client javascript.

Comment: I think you have to provide your own custom schema ... not sure how you'd go about doing this though (hence why it's not an answer)

Answer (score 2):

Goto Tools > Options > Text Editor > Html > Validation and turn it off.
Simples.

Comment: I don't want to turn off validation, it is useful. I just want to indicate that this custom attribute is acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

Since the HTML5 standard, you can define custom attributes with the prefix `data-`.

In your case, it will be `data-cid="MyCID"`. This will remove the warning.